# How to do the combination of 2 codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a code that tell what is the sign according to day and month
and I have another code that prints circles according to amount of circles that I enter in columns and rows.

any suggestions how I can combine between them?

for example if I enter 5 in columns and 5 in rows I get a message alert that my sign is Taurus

how to do that? is there any code that can combine between the both?

also is there any other easy suggestions how to combine astrology with the circles?

```js
$('#month, #day').on('input', maxDays);
$('button').on('click', zSign);

function maxDays() {
  var num = Number($(this).val());
  var max;

  if ($(this).is('#month')) {
    if (num % 2 === 0) {
      max = 30;
    } else if (num === 1) {
      max = 29;
    } else {
      max = 31;
    }
    return $('#day').attr('max', max).val('1');
  }

  if ($(this).is('#day')) {
    if (num < 1) {
      num = 1;
    } else if (num > max) {
      num = max;
    } else {
      num = num;
    }
    return $('#day').val(num);
  }
  return false;
}

function zSign() {
  var month = Number($('#month').val());
  var day = Number($('#day').val());
  var sign;

  switch (month) {
    case 0:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Capricorn" : "Aquarius";
      break;
    case 1:
      sign = day < 19 ? "Aquarius" : "Pisces";
      break;
    case 2:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Pisces" : "Aries";
      break;
    case 3:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Aries" : "Taurus";
      break;
    case 4:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Taurus" : "Gemini";
      break;
    case 5:
      sign = day < 22 ? "Gemini" : "Cancer";
      break;
    case 6:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Cancer" : "Leo";
      break;
    case 7:
      sign = day < 24 ? "Leo" : "Virgo";
      break;
    case 8:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Virgo" : "Libra";
      break;
    case 9:
      sign = day < 24 ? "Libra" : "Scorpio";
      break;
    case 10:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Scorpio" : "Sagittarius";
      break;
    case 11:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Sagittarius" : "Capricorn";
      break;
    default:
      sign = null;
      break;
  }
  return $('#output').val(sign);
}



function hoverTooltip(color, state) {
  tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
  tooltip.innerHTML = ''
  if (state == 'True') {
    var mouseX = event.clientX,
      mouseY = event.clientY;
    console.log(color);
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    tooltip.innerHTML = `Fill color:<br>${color}`;
    console.log('top: ' + mouseY + ' left:' + mouseX)
    tooltip.style.top = mouseY;
    tooltip.style.left = mouseX;
  } else {
    console.log("LEAVE");
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  /* Map HTML Button to JavaScript var */
  button = document.getElementById('userButton');
  button.onclick = function() {
    var rows = 0,
      cols = 0;
    tableHTMLContent = '';
    userRows = document.getElementById('userRows').value;
    userCols = document.getElementById('userCols').value;
    dynamicTable = document.getElementById('dynamicTable');
    if (userRows != '' && userCols != '') {
      for (row = 0; row < userRows; row++) {
        tableHTMLContent += '<tr>'
        for (col = 0; col < userCols; col++) {
          randomColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
          content = `<svg height="100" width="100"><circle onmouseenter="hoverTooltip('${randomColor}', 'True')" onmouseleave="hoverTooltip('', 'False')" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="${randomColor}" /></svg>`
          tableHTMLContent += `<td class='cicrle-cell'>${content}</td>`
        }
        tableHTMLContent += '</tr>'
      }
    } else {
      alert('Values are invalid, please insert numbers for both Rows an Cols')
    }
    dynamicTable.innerHTML = tableHTMLContent
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <style>
     :root {
      font: 500 16px/1.3 Verdana
    }
    
    select,
    input,
    output,
    button,
    label {
      display: inline-block;
      font: inherit;
      margin: 5px 1px;
    }
    
    #day {
      width: 4ch;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #output::before {
      content: "\a0";
    }
    
    #sign {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #tooltip {
      position: fixed;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      color: #eeffff;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>



  <div id=sign>
    <h1>what your sign?</h1>

    <form id="zodiac">
      <label for="month"> choose Month:</label>
      <select id="month">
        <option value='0' selected>January</option>
        <option value='1'>February</option>
        <option value='2'>March</option>
        <option value='3'>April</option>
        <option value='4'>May</option>
        <option value='5'>June</option>
        <option value='6'>July</option>
        <option value='7'>August</option>
        <option value='8'>September</option>
        <option value='9'>October</option>
        <option value='10'>November</option>
        <option value='11'>December</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <label for="day"> choose Day: </label>
      <input id="day" type='number' min='1' max='30' value='1'><br />
      <button type='button'>Done</button><br>
      <label for="output">Your sign is </label><output id='output'></output>
    </form>
    <form>
      Rows:
      <input id="userRows" type='text'> Cols:
      <input id="userCols" type='text'>
      <input id="userButton" type="button" value="Generate" su>
    </form>
    <div id="tooltip">
    </div>
    <table id="dynamicTable"></table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd start by correcting your HTML page structure. You don't have an opening `head` tag and you can't have `style` in the `body`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)